# Решение примера в виде строки php

Tags: php, строки, подстрока

Есть пример '(23+8)*(9-231*32)' в строке, его нужно решить по математическим правилам. Сначала скобки, потом умножение, деление, сложение вычитание.
В javascript есть ParseInt, в php такого нет. У меня только вариант через substr делать, но, возможно, есть более простые способы.

Comment: Вообще и в js и в php есть eval функция. Нужно единственно подправить строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В php парсинн проходит немного по другому

```
$num = "3.14";
$int = (int)$num;
$float = (float)$num;
```

А на счёт вычисления простого арифметического выражения можно использовать `eval()` функцию. Единственно нужно будет вставить опущенные умножения